# iOS private api usage: _Unwind_Resume

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios7, iphone-privateapi

I'm trying to prepare an app for review for iOS7, and I just hit this brick wall:

The app references non-public symobls in....**_Unwind_Resume**

[image: screenshot of issue]

Inside of Release-iphoneos, I tried to find the culprit with 
`nm -u *.a | grep -C 20 Unwind_Resume`

but it looks like every dependency lists `Unwind_Resume` at some point.

What could possibly be causing this? How do I debug this from here?

Comment: `_Unwind_resume` resumes unwinding after cleanup occurred because of an exception. This necessarily happens if you use C++ or ObjC++. I'm not sure why Apple flags this as "private API": the calls are (or should be) compiler-generated. I'd ask Apple about this one.

Comment: I figured something like this was the case. I emailed the support contact ASAP after I got that message. I was really hoping to be available day 1 of iOS7. Argh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I binary searched across my commits, and at some point, I screwed up the project.pbx* settings. One of my pod dependencies had build-active-architecture-only set to YES.

I moved back in commits, set all the architecture targets again, and I passed validation.

Answer (score 3):

Our iOS library was causing validation errors for our developers as well - the fix for our library ended up being quite simple.

1. Run Product > Analyze (against the library, not the app!)
2. Fix any "API misuse" errors - for us it was a couple of random 'parameter may be null' notices
3. Rebuild

That fixed it up for us and our customers and had nothing to do with `Unwind_Resume` or any private apis.

Comment: I did this, saw two issues, corrected them, and same error message.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed now in the App Store Validator.  Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by rebuilding without 64-bit enabled. To disable building for 64-bit in Xcode:

- Select the app in the file browser on the right
- Got to the 'Build Settings' tab in the main window
- Scroll down to the architectures group and look at the value of the Architectures setting.
- Is it set to 'Standard architectures (including 64-bit). If so, switch to 'Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s)'

I'm unsure whether this is a bug in the validation stage, or if it's there to prevent developers from submitting 64-bit apps before anyone has actual hardware to test on.

--Chris